# Заполнение и отправка формы POST запросом C#

Tags: c#, post

Писал авто тест по заполнению и отправки формы, делал все это через userInterface, с помощью селениум.
Сегодня узнал что можно тоже самое делать только через POST запрос.

Есть форма. В форме поле "Название","Текст", Кнопка "Сохранить"

Как выполнить действия по заполнению полей и нажатия кнопки Сохранить, post запросом?

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/admin/content/contents/create
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Remote Address:127.0.0.1
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Mon, 29 May 2017 07:27:53 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Location:http://localhost:8080/admin/content/contents/index
Pragma:no-cache
Server:nginx/1.8.0
Request Headers
view source
```

Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate

Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

```
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:289
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:user_lang=ru;     YII_CSRF_TOKEN=d4242e009637469aaa9049e10027b6950cea195d;     user_basket=734966a2f6efbd4131880f02848ae281307d629e;     PHPSESSID=mo934sblvv33dn3kvua6kpjop6;     backurl=http%3A//localhost:8080/admin/content/contents/create
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/admin/content/contents/create
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded

YII_CSRF_TOKEN:d4242e009637469aaa9049e10027b6950cea195d
ContentsLang[lang]:ru
ContentsLang[text]:<p>test Article poas name</p>
ContentsLang[name]:test Article post
area[textareackeditor]:<p>test Article poas name</p>
area[textareablock]:
```

Comment: Установить  Postman и Postman Interceptor. Interceptor'ом поймать запрос, Постманом сгенерить код для C#

Comment: Если хотите написать C# код, который будет отправлять post-запрос, то посмотрите класс WebRequest и документацию по нему. Там все довольно просто